# Cropping an image with imcrop() in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, crop

I'm having trouble in cropping an image in MATLAB. The code is as follows:

```
n = 128;
% M0 = rescale(imcrop(x_gray,n));
[xx, xy] = size(x_gray);
M0 = rescale(imcrop(x_gray, 1, 1, n, n));
```

The size of x_gray is 384x512:

```
>> size(x_gray)
ans =
   384   512
```

imcrop() gives the following error:

```
Attempted to access spatial_rect(4); index out
of bounds because numel(spatial_rect)=1.

Error in imcrop (line 128)
pixelHeight = spatial_rect(4) *
pixelsPerVerticalUnit;
```

Why is the index out of bounds? The syntax of imcrop is:

```
B = imcrop(A,[xmin ymin width height]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same error as you, because the syntax you use is incorrect. Place the coordinates of your rectangle (i.e. 1,1,n,n) inside square brackets and it should work:

```
M0 = rescale(imcrop(x_gray, [1 1 n n]));
```

Comment: I also noticed that rescale doesn't work. The correct syntax is M0 = imresize(imcrop(x_gray, [1, 1, n, n]), [xx xy]); . +1 btw

Comment: Great it worked! I confess I only tried to crop and not "rescale" my test image; I was not sure the function existed. If it solved your problem can you mark the answer as "Accepted" so that the thread is closed? Thanks!